# How can I get my co-workers to migrate to a new system without being too pushy?

Tags: technology

A few weeks ago I migrated our team repository from SVN to Git (just think of it as something we work with once to multiple times a day). As I expected the challenge wasn't the technical part but getting people to switch. My manager had expressed the desire to move to Git so I had taken the initiative as I felt confident and experienced enough to do so. Since then:

- I sent a couple of emails with simple instructions on how to setup indicating I'm available for questions and help
- I've demoed our new repo, showing everyone how it works and explaining Git
- My manager pointed out on a few occasions that he expected everyone to move to Git soon
- I made a test repository we intend to scrap just as a sandbox for people not to be intimidated by it.

Yet, no one's taken the steps to migrate just yet.

We're all adults here and I hate going after people asking if they've done something, I feel even more uncomfortable pressing the question since I'm new at this company (a month roughly).

I understand change is difficult and uncomfortable, what's a good way to deal with this situation without being too pushy yet without it dragging forever ?

Comment: Do you have a migration plan and have it communicated precisely? e.g. Projects X and Y will continue to use svn for maintenance purposes. Project Z is using svn until the end of the month. All commits on Project Z as of 1 Feb must be made via Git. All new projects must use Git. etc.

Comment: Was there an actual date communicated for when to use Git? If not, then that is likely the problem as if everyone is thinking to stick with SVN then that is what they will do as someone has to draw the line in the sand if you want this to work.

Comment: You don't mention whether or not you were tasked, authorised and empowered by management to do this. Without these you are unlikely to succeed and may face hostility

Comment: @ChrisR like I said in the question, it was an initiative on my part and when I notified my manager he didn't disapprove, he seemed pleased

Comment: @JBKing my manager set two different dates, but he didn't follow up with the team because he was busy

Comment: You also need, in a business environment to engender peer acceptance before going ahead. For example I am in a particularly difficult and time pressed phase in my project, I now have to change repositories inthe middle of that work and still keep deadlines. Hmmmm i@d be annoyed and just keep using SVN till I get a gap.

Comment: To put it bluntly: it's not your job. Leave it to the manager unless you are a _de facto_ team leader.

Comment: The right software (ie: [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/)) may encourage a quicker transition amongst your peers. Command-line git can still be a little intimidating, even for people who know how to code.

Comment: @LindseyD I'm aware of that, during the demo I used a graphical client

Comment: There is a huge difference between technical change management and organizational change management. Any good change manager (de jure or de facto) needs to take into consideration both.

Comment: Transitioning to Git can be a bit intimidating if you haven't used it before. [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1597/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be strange if the SVN server started to act weird now? I bet the IT guy can confirm the power plug was plugged in yesterday, but today, strangely... while rebooting after plugging it in again, you notice that some of the files got corrupted. Good that you backed them up on GIT yesterday! And is it just me or does a commit to SVN take forever now? As if they added some `sleep(2000)` to the code of that version we recently updated to.

Comment: One way to help make the transition a little smoother is to have everyone committing straight to master branch until they get used to the toolset instead of doing something like "git flow" right off the bat. this way they get used to things like adding to the index, then committing, and then pushing rather than simply committing.

Comment: When my favorite open source project switched from SVN to Git I was also very sceptical at first, but [the presentation by Linus Torvalds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8) convinced me.

Comment: Note on "* Ihad taken the initiative as I felt confident and experienced enough to do so*" If you started at this company as a regular employee **a month ago** then you are in no way experienced enough to take the lead in changing an existing team's workflow. Frankly, if you didn't even consider a migration plan then you probably shouldn't be in charge of anything.

Comment: Even bosses who say they're supportive really don't want to be bothered. They are quite willing to let you do whatever you want, but with that comes the fact that they're willing to let everyone else do what they want as well. Chalk it up to a lesson learned that even if you get lip service from your boss, you need something more concrete than that before you can count on real support. What would that be? Heck if I know. I've been where you are, but I'm not sure there was ever a successful transition to the new process.

Comment: I wonder if OP has done the research to know whether transitioning to Git is the right call for the team. There are alternatives to Git for DVCS and if you're going to go through the hassle of making a change, you might as well change to the best tool for the job. If the team hasn't been consulted in this change then it's quite likely that there are other options that haven't been explored.

Comment: Moving from SVN to git can be tricky because you need to unlearn some concepts. Once they get it they'll realise the benefit but it is hard to get over that hump.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Build a case

Why is this change needed?

Everything in your post talks about the logistics of switching. Did you build a case for actually switching? Does your team know how much better Git is for your team than SVN?

When persuading, people forget that the people they need to persuade do not necessarily know "why" something is needed. You probably are familiar with Git and think "of course Git is better than SVN!", but your team probably does not.

This is all important even if the ultimate reason is "because boss says so" as it helps with the process change even if the core motivation is "management."

---

## Are you sure people git it?

Git is a different paradigm than SVN. If you gave a presentation it's entirely possible that no one really understood. And if you don't understand a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) you are going to be very resistant to changing to it.

When you give a presentation, make sure to ask open ended questions like "What questions do you have?" instead of "Do you have any questions?"

An email likely was completely ineffective, since most people get many emails and a "FYI change coming!" email often go straight into the "not relevant" category.

---

## Who's in charge?

Your question is... interesting in that your assignment of responsibility is fairly passive voice. Did your manager task you with leading the initiative? Or is your manager still responsible?

Someone needs to have ultimate ownership for the project. In your position, I would **strongly** encourage you to find a way to get your boss to drive the conversation.

You don't want to be the "new guy who makes everyone change everything" after a month...

---

## What to do?

First, I'd set up a meeting with your manager. Talk with them about:

- What you did (presentations, etc.)
- What was the outcome you expected (people to change)
- What was the outcome that actually happened (people didn't change)
- Ask what your next steps should be

  - You can even say you don't want to be pushy as the new person
  - Maybe ask about a timeline (perhaps your understanding of "soon" was very different)

Now, if your manager has no idea what is going on (unlikely... but possible) you will want to make sure they understand the implications of changing.

Understanding that it is not a "some-people-switch-to-Git-slowly-while-others-work-in-SVN" approach is important. Ultimately someone needs to have a plan, with a specific date/timeframe when Git goes live. You want to come out of this meeting either knowing this information or trusting your manager either has a plan or will create a plan.

Likely your manager, if even remotely competent, will take ownership and resolve this quickly at this point. If not, they will have a better understanding of team culture and can provide better specific steps.

Comment: "it's entirely possible that no one really understood". It's git, no-one *really* understands it. [(obligatory xkcd)](https://xkcd.com/1597/)

Comment: @StuperUser - Git is perhaps the most appropriately named piece of software, ever. (Various four letter pieces of software named **** that no one uses excluded.)

Comment: @DavidHammen: Linus Torvalds said in a talk somewhere (to Google I think) that he's known for two pieces of software, Linux and git, both named after himself.

Comment: "Are you sure people git it?" I see what you did there.

Comment: Starting to feel like I'm the only guy in the world who likes monotonic revision numbers, properties, how merging works, how everything is a file and there's nothing special, and the theoretic purity of diffs and merge info.....

Comment: @DigitalChris I'd be very surprised if anyone *didn't* see it. It's hardly subtle.

Comment: @StuperUser here ya go. [Watch this talk by Edward Thompson, git guru](http://youtu.be/dBSHLb1B8sw). Now you understand Git.

Comment: @immibis you'd be surprised what gits past people without them noticing.

Answer (score 70):

If the manager expressed the desire to move to Git (or any other new technology) then it is *their* responsibility to notify everyone that the change will be effective by a specified date (X days from the announcement).

The announcement should be explicit that the new technology will be active and fully functional by the said date, and at the same time, the old technology will be made obsolete, either by removing it, or in that case, make the SVN repository read-only.

The announcement should be made by the manager. The announcement should also include something like: "If you have concerns about the new technology, please come to see me and discuss it".

Comment: I think your solution could be the solution right here, but more generally, it is common for a manager to delegate not just tasks but also authority to an employee. This is particular common and even desirable on small teams and teams consisting of skilled workers.

Comment: +1 for disabling/ROing the old solution.  Users only change when they have no other choice (says the sysadmin), which is why no migration is ever truly complete until the old system is gone.  Whether you give them advance notice and reminders or just yank the rug out from under them one day is a matter of personal preference, IMO.

Comment: When we switched to git, we switched the build servers over too. Once people figured out their changes weren't making it into the build because they were still using SVN, they switched over pretty quickly.

Comment: @JoshRumbut, agreed, if it is the case, then the manager should also notify the team that employee Y is in charge of the task.

Comment: Agree with this. It's like when you get a new laptop, you always keep your old one just in case there is something on the hard drive you need and have forgotten about, until someone says "right - your old laptop is being wiped and given to someone else"

Comment: IMO, if the manager wants to move to Git and you already put in the time and smoothly transitioned everything, just inform the manager that the transition is set up and all he has to do is execute it.

Comment: Follow the advice in this answer only if you're willing to alienate your coworkers and breed resentment. The best way to affect change among coworkers is to have them *want* to change. Telling them they **must** is an excellent way to ensure that they don't.

Comment: @zzzzBov you might not be entirely wrong, but trust me, you don't want the mess of people committing their changes to two different version control systems. Flipping the switch is the right thing to do, but it really does need to come down from mgmt.

Answer (score 14):

In your entire question, I don't hear a single reason *why* anyone *benefits* by using git.

The truth is, you'll hit a learning curve and a bit of re-tooling that will slow people down in the short term. There are many valid reasons to move to git, and I would never go back to svn myself, git is vastly superior in many ways--but that's not the point. I use git, know it, and know what I like it. If I received an email saying I had to switch with no real benefit spelled out, and knowing it would trip me up for a while, I'd wait until threatened before bothering. Someone else may argue you into a corner, and then I can ignore this and go on working. There may be a history of this for other edicts from above.

So how do you deal with people ignoring you?  Sit with someone influential and see if you can switch him over. You may have to do that 2-3 times. Then let them do the evangelizing. If they don't, feed back upstream that the top people see no benefit, and it's a waste of resources.  In this case I don't think that will happen, since the workflow changes git introduces do have benefits.

Comment: Furthermore, until the task "learn how to use git and switch over" has a priority and a deadline, then it's often quite difficult to justify taking the time to do so, in preference to working on other tasks, even for those who otherwise wouldn't need threatening. So even evangelizing isn't enough on its own.

Comment: Unless merging of branches is an issue, I fail to see how a move to git from a WORKING svn setup will ever be worth it.

Answer (score 7):

This is an eternal challenge when leading developers, we're very stubborn.

Something to ask yourself, and communicate to the team, is why the switch was made. Was it too much time spent dealing with merge conflicts? Collaboration with a git-centric team? The desire to use some sort of tooling?

If the switch was made for a vague reason or the manager's personal preference, this resistance is to be entirely expected and maybe even they have a point. If it was to solve a problem or take advantage of an opportunity, the team needs to know what pain they will no longer have to experience, or what benefits they can expect.

Listen to their concerns, and make sure the git setup is addressing them. If they have legitimate concerns, reconsider the switch. Plenty of successful projects are using SVN.

Once this communication happens, I would set a date and shut down the SVN server. Don't release anything not committed to the central git repo. Don't keep the SVN server up just in case someone can't figure out the commits are local now and need to be pushed, when they have to make the change they will, and before that they probably won't.

Comment: `the team needs to know what pain they will no longer have to experience` This should be your biggest take-away. My team switched from CVS to Git mainly because our 10-years-of-development CVS repository was taking upwards of 20 minutes to create a new tag and a new branch, which we each had to do for every single task/ticket, whereas Git could both tag and branch in seconds. A major pain point removed, so everyone was genuinely *excited* about the change.

Answer (score 7):

**A confused mind always says "NO".**

I've migrated several customers from SVN to git and help establish git policy and workflow.  The #1 problem ***is*** ***technical***.

Git has a profoundly different philosophy behind it than SVN.

**Doing a single demo will *not* suffice for daily technical usage.**

Trying to use git, particularly if you come from an svn background will at first seem easy, and then become very confusing.  **Confusing = NO.**

You do not say how well versed you are in git, but you should at least be a few steps ahead of everyone else before you attempt to move them.  Otherwise, a lack of knowledge about how to use git and solve problems in git will be a further deterrent.

I recommend that you write a document about how to do **daily** tasks (are you a rebase shop or merge shop? are you using any git workflows?), solve problems, use branches (a very POWERFUL feature of git), pull and push, and finally recover from a merge conflict.

Once you have that, then you'll give them comfort that they'll be able to use the new system.

Then, choose a repo and get with the developers that work on that code and ask them to switch, and STAY WITH THEM.   Turn off svn for that project and make their move as easy as possible by STAYING WITH THEM.  Tell them you'd like them to pilot it.  STAY WITH THEM when they do their first 5 - 10 pull/merge/push tasks.

**Once they get used to it, and find out how to "think" in "git" then they will be your biggest advocates.**

Then, repeat with the rest.

Comment: I would actually go a few steps further in simplifying things. Having used git for a while, my (untested) policy for introducing new people to git would be to teach them clone, commit, push, pull, and about .gitignore. This represents, imo, the *minimal* subset for getting started. Yes, you'll make a bit of a mess of the repo that way (prolly merge commits getting created from pulls and such), but at least people can start using it. Once they have the basics down, they can start learning how to manage merges and rebases and the like. Trying to introduce all that up front is too intimidating.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Good points, - especially .gitignore - we also talk about what a repo actually is, and branching and how branching can be used to experiment.  One of the first exercises is to do exactly what you have in your list - and in a separate branch.  You are right the commit history can get dirty, but the beauty of git is that it can always be cleaned up later.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case (SVN to Git) I am not sure if it is useful to *force* the change onto all users. There are Git-SVN bridges available (eg. [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) or [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/)) which give interested developers most of the advantages of Git while allowing other developers to keep using SVN.

The underlying idea is to tell your developers *what* to achieve, not *how* to achieve it. Here are the pros and cons of this approach, based on my experiences with git-svn:

Pros:

- people can switch from SVN to Git in their own time, rather than having to take time out in a stressful phase
- trailblazing developers can experiment with Git, can develop company-specific workflows, can find pitfalls, and can later teach their colleagues
- people can realize the usefulness of the new tool just by seeing their colleagues using it
- or, if the new tool is actually not an improvement, only the trailblazers will have to migrate back, reducing the costs sunk into a bad decision
- some trailblazing developer might actually find that eg. Mercurial+SVN is a much better tool for your work than Git+SVN. By not forcing specific tools onto developers they might come up with better solutions.

Cons:

- developers will feel encouraged to spend work hours for finding their own perfect VCS solution. Then again, this might happen anyway.
- some developers might never try the bridge software at all (due to laziness or unwillingness to learn new tools). If you finally want to switch from SVN to Git for real, you still have to deal with these people
- you can't use the new tool in all aspects (eg. git-svn still has some drawbacks versus a native central Git repository)
- you send the message that decisions are made by developers, not by management. Management itself might not like this message; also, developers might get too free-wheeling in future decisions. IMO this is an acceptable tradeoff, but in some businesses it might not be.
- if you have other reasons for a tool change (like, pressure from further-up management, or technical reasons brought on by Sysadmin department), the actual decision must probably be made by management and not be developers
- this approach only works for very specific cases. Switching from CVS to Git this way would be very difficult already, and switching eg. your bugtracking tool this way might not be possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your boss abdicated this responsibility to you instead of delegating it. He didn't offer any suggestions on how to persuade the others and probably wanted you to break the bad news so he didn't have to listen to everyone complain.

It would be nice to know why the other team moved to Git so everyone could decide if it makes sense for everyone else to use it. Are you all going to be working on the same project? Does it make it easier to shuffle developers from one project to the other with at least not being concerned about whether or not they know how the code is being managed?

I realize people don't like change, but when you have sound reasons for doing things, many people will follow even if it is not their preference. Get some insight and possibly a level of authority from your manager to be more persuasive or he's going to have to do it himself.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very useful skill to be able to effect change in an organization without having the authority to mandate it. It takes a light touch and explicit consideration of your audience.  In many organizations, it's the only way to get things done.  As it happens, my current role is all about being able to bring a larger organization with me to better technologies and processes.

The first step is to understand where the team is right now. Learn the specifics of their problems. Find out what the current technology (SVN) does well for them and what problems it has. Understand why they're working the way they are. Maybe they're doing some things that seem suboptimal, but it's not the technology driving those actions, but because there's something else they want that those things enable. For example, parts of my current company use a source control tool that is really, really bad for developers using source control, but offers a clear and automated promotion path to production across a number of (legacy) technologies. A big part of this is to understand all of the different people affected by a solution: it may not only be the developers accessing source control, but the release managers, the people involved in deployments, the auditing team, etc.

Step two: figure out what your proposed solution is going to improve for them, and figure out what else needs to be there so they don't lose the qualities of the old solution that are working for them. The organization's goal is to make things better! So you need to know precisely what the new solution will make better, what it will make worse, and ensure that things are better overall than they would be otherwise.  And if at all possible, make it better for all stakeholders!  If something is better for dev but harder for release management, you will have a fight. If you can make things better for both groups, you will get people to agree. To continue the example, you could use Git for developer source control but then automatically deliver artifacts to the old tool for deployment. You've made life better for dev while retaining the parts that worked well for operations.

Next, start small and learn. Pick a small group of people and get them to start using the new solution. This is important for two reasons. First, you need to start small so that you can ensure that it works. You can work out any problems. You can find things you missed. But more importantly, as one person you can only work with and educate so many people at once. During this initial phase, you are building a group of people that can help on the front lines with questions and advocacy. (This is often called "train the trainer.")  Let the advantages shine through: "You mean I don't need to waste an hour and a half doing merges every sprint?  You mean it tracks not only package changes but moved functions?" Assuming that the change is a good one, you should be able to make these people your cheerleaders.

After this, repeat with larger groups. Ensure you understand their needs, their problems. Show them the value of the change. Your solution may adapt as it reaches larger groups. That's OK. Different teams have different needs, which is why nobody in a large company is upset that some people use MS Word and others use InDesign.

Nowhere in the above do you need HR authority to mandate a change. In fact, the need to resort to "Do this because I'm your boss" usually shows a failure to follow the above steps, because either you don't understand why a change makes things better for people or because it doesn't make things better for some people but you will force them to do it anyway. (Unfortunately, things like audit and security often come down like this: making things easier for one group but harder for another, without finding a way for both teams to win.)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are new, I normally wouldn't take responsibility for something like this. It may seem weird, but maybe they still see you as 'the new one'.

I would still go after them, and say they have to migrate and it's an order from the manager. Don't go all mad but just politely say it. You'll not achieve anything by being mad. Don't be afraid to tell others what to do as you have to be able to do those kind of things in a company.

Maybe you could ask them why they didn't listen to the email, though I doubt it will help it could let you know why they didn't migrate yet.

---

Don't just keep on emailing. The manager can ask you why not everybody migrated yet since you took the responsibility, if you say you emailed them, told them in person and they still didn't listen, it's less of a problem then then when you only emailed them.

Comment: I'm not mad, I just want this to go well. I don't feel I'm in a position to tell them what to do as I'm just a peer in the team, not in any managerial or position of "authority"

Comment: Didn't say you were, I was just saying it. And you might not feel like, but you have to as you took the responsibility. How weird it might seem you you're basically the 'manager' of the migration process.

Comment: They should take responsibility for the technical side of things (i.e. setting it up) and maybe even the training, but they should leave the manager to communicate *their* (not the OP's) expectations about this being adopted, when it's going to be migrated to, etc. Coming in as a new hire and telling people they have to do X, and then following up asking why they haven't, isn't going to win them any good favour with their colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

People are busy and, by default, often won't take time away from their work to do something that they feel is unproductive. Often, the only way to deal with a situation like this is to use a stick as well as a carrot.

For example, as well as the demos, emails and instructions etc. you need to set a deadline for users to migrate. Once the deadline has been met, maybe offer a few day's grace period and then remove their access from SVN. If they still require access, have them submit a request to management to have it re-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

If you offer 2 ways of doing things, make both ways available, and allow both ways to be used, **that is not a migration**. It's the creation of chaos.

To migrate people on a new system you need to actually migrate. This needs a migration plan. A migration plan can be as simple as *"From Monday, all new work will need to be checked in to git, svn will be used only for the existing release branches and no new branches will be created in svn. Mr Tony Lao is responsible to answer any questions you have on git, and will follow up with anyone who violates the new policy."*

A good migration plan gives people advance warning, lets people provide input (and acts on that input)*, communicates each step clearly, and is flexible to change. If anyone is surprised once svn is turned off, the migration plan failed miserably.

*If people tell you they don't want to move to git, they will provide reasons. Listen to them, not to convince them, but because they may be right. If the team doesn't want to move, and the manager doesn't want to force them, there will be no move.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason for you to try to force everyone to use git. Let people adopt it as they see fit. Our company which is small has an SVN server and a git server and project managers can choose which one they want to use.

Arbitrarily forcing people to use tools you favor is a morale-busting move. Don't do it.

Also, as I am sure you are aware git is significantly more complex than SVN because it is a peer-to-peer system. That is great if you are doing a highly diversified open source project. But for simple, top-down projects with a single manager, the extra flexibility git provides is largely superfluous.

I use git for my own personal hobby projects because I bounce around a lot from different computers, but at work I continue to use SVN because it is a more simple model and at work we have zero need for peer-to-peer functionality. In fact, for the projects at work I do not want git because creating private repositories is exactly what I DON'T want people doing.

Comment: This wasn't so arbitrary though, another team is preparing a Git move as well and like I said, my manager had told me he had a project to move our team to Git

Comment: Having different developers use different source control is a recipe for disaster. This is very bad advice.

Comment: Great, now I am going to get downvoted by every Git jihadist on the planet. Look, we do this already in my company and it is not a "disaster". It works perfectly fine and everybody loves it. Zero drama. Trying to force switchovers will create drama and unhappiness which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Git isn't "a peer-to-peer system", it's perfectly happy being centralized. That's what github.com is.

Comment: @blackbird57 - Does the answer to this question, fit your situation?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion

Comment: But version control is one of the rare things you DO all have to be doing the same with. Now, if my boss wanted to dictate what TOOL I used for git, that would be an issue (or what IDE I should use). I can't begin to fathom a group of devs and having people use differing source control systems.

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't downvote you because I'm a git jihadist. I downvoted you because this answer does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm not a git jihadist, either, but I too downvoted. You said so yourself, @Socrates: *project managers can choose which one they want to use*. The project manager in question chose to switch to git. While there is a way to personally use git when the project uses SVN for version control, the reverse isn't possible. The project manager chose to switch the project from subversion to git, and now the team members have to either get on board, switch to another project, or switch employers.